# RegisterClientScriptBlock nor RegisterStartupScript are executing the script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have `Index.aspx` there I have this :

```
<iframe id="dyna" src="~/Home.aspx" runat="server" onload="dyna_Load" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"  style="border:none" ></iframe>
```

and inside `Index.aspx.cs` :

```
protected void dyna_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "illumez", "alert('test')", true);
    }
```

The `RegisterClientScriptBlock / RegisterStartupScript` are being called , but the javascript not being executed! what am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your `iframe.onload` is looking for a javascript function called `dyna_load`. It cannot execute C# code. The script you are registering should execute when Index.aspx is loaded. If you want the script to execute when the iframe is loaded place your script registration in Home.aspx.cs.

Comment: that's not true , it executes the C# code!! because it run at `server`

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. Either way I would suggest moving your script registration into either page's OnLoad, not the iframe.